# mysqli_connect() не работает

Tags: php, mysql

версия php 8

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $database = "plazashopbd";
    $username = "123123";
    $password = "123123";
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    if

 (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

код возвращает такую ошибку (база данных кста существует):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в файл php.ini

Возможно в нём строка  подключением расширения (extension) закомментирована и надо раскомментировать

Или, в линукс системе надо доставить его. Примерно так

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mysqli
sudo phpenmod mysqli
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: там их 2: ini-development и ini-production и в них все закомментировано

Comment: вы не туда смотрите. всегда есть активный php.ini  не development и production. значит один из них надо переименовать в php.ini  и там уже смотреть.........но скорее всего вы не туда смотрите

Comment: у xampp  и openServer  есть файлы настроек, которые редактируются.

Answer (score 0):

если линукс попробуйте установить пакет `sudo apt install php-mysqli`, а потом сделайте рестарт apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: а если винда, то как пакет скачать?

Comment: @44421 https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Answer (score 0):

Нужно зайти в папку с PHP, открыть файл php.ini и раскомментировать **;extension=php_mysqli**, убрав точку с запятой.